# d3 - Can't return data from json request?

Tags: json, ajax, d3.js

I'm trying to use `d3.json()` inside of a function to return data Spotify's API given an artist ID (such as [5K4W6rqBFWDnAN6FQUkS6x](https://open.spotify.com/artist/5K4W6rqBFWDnAN6FQUkS6x)), but I can't figure out how to effectively return the data. The function looks like

```
// Get artist's related artist's information
function relatedArtists(id){
  var jsonPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Async JSON request
    d3.json('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + id + '/related-artists', function(error, data){
      if(error) reject(error);
      resolve(data.artists);
    });
  });

  jsonPromise.then(function(success) {
    console.log(success);
    //return(success)  //doesn't work
  });

  jsonPromise.catch(function(error){
    console.error(error);
  });

}
```

I've tried creating a variable within the function and then modifying it

```
function relatedArtists(id){
  var testVar = 'hello';
  var jsonPromise = new Promise(...{
    // Async JSON request
    d3.json(...)
  });
  jsonPromise.then(function(success) {
    testVar = success;
  });
  return(testVar);
}
```

But `testVar` remains `'hello'`, despite my best efforts. I've done some reading about scope and promises, but am happy to do more if there's some core mechanic of either that I'm not understanding. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return `Promise` and use `relatedArtists` function like so

```js
function relatedArtists(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    d3.json('https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + id + '/related-artists', function(error, data) {
      if (error) {
       reject(error);
      } else {
       resolve(data.artists);
      }
    });
  });
}


relatedArtists('5K4W6rqBFWDnAN6FQUkS6x')
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

In this case, you can not assign the value to `testVar`, because `d3.json` is the asynchronous method and that means that  `d3.json` can be done after code execution.

Answer (score 5):

The response will never be available in your calling code due to asynchronous nature of requests. You can use Promises (as supposed by Alexander T. and you, good choice in many cases!) but [`d3.queue`](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue/blob/master/README.md#d3-queue) does a good job, too. In my snippet you can see how to run code with the results of multiple requests.

```js
function buildRelatedArtistUri(id) {
  return 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/' + id + '/related-artists';
}

d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, buildRelatedArtistUri('5K4W6rqBFWDnAN6FQUkS6x'))
  .await(function(error, data) {
    // data and data.artists are available in this function‘s scope only
    console.log(data.artists);
  });

d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, buildRelatedArtistUri('5K4W6rqBFWDnAN6FQUkS6x'))
  .defer(d3.json, buildRelatedArtistUri('3nFkdlSjzX9mRTtwJOzDYB'))
  .await(function(error, data1, data2) {
    // this function will be called once both functions have finished
    console.log(data1.artists, data2.artists);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Oh, this is really cool- so `d3.queue` is a way of deferring actions until a request completes? This seems really useful, thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can defer any callback-consuming async function. On top, you can configure [concurrency](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue/blob/master/README.md#queue) and make tasks [abortable](https://github.com/d3/d3-queue/blob/master/README.md#queue_abort)…